# Why can't I define an object first and then send that object as a body in post requests? (React)

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm trying to do a simple POST request using React's fetch() method, but when I try to add my data object to the body of that request it gets undefined when it arrives in my express-based back-end (and yes, i'm already using body-parser etc.).

However, if I instead define the body directly in the fetch() method by manually adding the properties, it suddenly works the way I want it to.

This is on the client-side:

```
addProduct = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = {
        namn: this.state.curNamn,
        lagersaldo: this.state.curSaldo,
        plats: this.state.curPlats
    }

    if (this.checkEmptyValues(data)) {
        alert("Please fill in all the fields");
        return;
    }  

    fetch('http://localhost:3001/addproduct', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({data})
    })
    .then(res => this.resolveRes(res))  
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
```

And on the server-side:

```
app.post('/addproduct', (req, res) => {

let data = {
    namn: req.body.namn,
    lagersaldo: req.body.lagersaldo,
    plats: req.body.plats
};

let sql = 'INSERT INTO produkter SET ?';
db.query(sql, data, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(result);
});
```

});

So the above code gives me a 'ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR' since the properties of the body are undefined when it arrives on the server-side, but If i were to change the code to this it works:

```
addProduct = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (this.checkEmptyValues(data)) {
        alert("Please fill in all the fields");
        return;
    }  

    fetch('http://localhost:3001/addproduct', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
           namn: this.state.curNamn,
           lagersaldo: this.state.curSaldo,
           plats: this.state.curPlats
        })
     })
    .then(res => this.resolveRes(res))  
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
```

Why is this? Why can't i just define and create the object that i want to send first, and then just send that object in the body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrapping your data inside a another object

```
JSON.stringify({data})
// This gets stringified to:
{
  data: {
    namn: ...,
    lagersaldo: ...,
    plats: ...
  }
}
```

Replace with:

```
JSON.stringify(data)
//Stringifies to:
{
  namn: ...,
  lagersaldo: ...,
  plats: ...
}
```

Comment: Ahh god damnit I feel stupid now lol. Thanks man, I got it now!

Answer (score 0):

Your are sending data in another object here:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001/addproduct', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({data})
})
```

You should spread data if you have to add something

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001/addproduct', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({
      ...data,
      newFixValue: true
    })
})
```

or just send data like this:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001/addproduct', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
```